# JavaScript OOP error

Tags: javascript

Hello this is my first attempt at trying to write a JavaScript application so I'm new to writing OOP code using it.

The following code runs without any errors in the console:

```
// Main file for the application
$(document).ready( function()
{
    var app = new application;
    setInterval( app.run, 50 );

});

function application()
{
   var canvas = Raphael(10,0,400,400);
   this.molecule = new molecule( new Vec2(50,50),new Vec2(1,0),canvas );
   this.molecule.update(10);

   this.run = function()
    {

    }
}
```

However, this piece of code does not work:

```
// Main file for the application
$(document).ready( function()
{
    var app = new application;
    setInterval( app.run, 50 );

});

function application()
{
   var canvas = Raphael(10,0,400,400);
   this.molecule = new molecule( new Vec2(50,50),new Vec2(1,0),canvas );

   this.run = function()
    {
        this.molecule.update(10);
    }
}
```

It gives the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function molecule( pos,vel,canvas )
    {
        this.radius = 5;
        this.color = "red";

        this.canvas = canvas;

        this.pos = pos;
        this.vel = vel;

        this.circle = canvas.circle( this.pos.x,this.pos.y,this.radius );

        this.circle.attr("fill", this.color );


    } has no method 'update'
```

Here is the source file containing the molecule object.

```
    // This 'class' handles a molecule, including movement and drawing.

    function molecule( pos,vel,canvas )
    {
        this.radius = 5;
        this.color = "red";

        this.canvas = canvas;

        this.pos = pos;
        this.vel = vel;

        this.circle = canvas.circle( this.pos.x,this.pos.y,this.radius );

        this.circle.attr("fill", this.color );


    }

 // Updates the molecule
    molecule.prototype.update = function( deltaTime )
    {
        this.pos += this.vel * deltaTime;
        this.setPosition(this.pos);
    }

    // Accepts a Vec2
    molecule.prototype.setPosition = function( pos )
    {
        this.circle.translate( pos.x-this.pos.x, pos.y-this.pos.y );
    }
```

I'm sorry for the large amount of code I've posted, but I'm stumped why the first piece of code works while the second won't. Could anybody shed some light on it for me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common mistake, and it requires a good understanding of JavaScript to see what's happening here. The problem is this line:

```
setInterval( app.run, 50 );
```

This causes `app.run` to be called when the interval runs out *without a proper `this` context*. To ensure that `run` gets called with `app` as its `this` context, you need something like:

```
setInterval( function() {
    app.run();
}, 50 );
```

or with the latest JavaScript (only in very modern browsers):

```
setInterval( app.run.bind(app), 50 );
```

The `this` context of a function in JavaScript is determined by how the function is called. Basically, it gets determined by what object it is called on. For example, in `app.run()`, the `run` method is called on `app` and it'll work as expected. However, in a slightly different scenario

```
var fn = app.run;
fn();
```

the function is called on no object and thus `this` will not be set, leading to unexpected results. This is exactly what's happening in your case. The solution is to make sure that you pass a function which can be called on any object, and make that function call `run` on the right object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I'm new to the way it works in JavaScript and just expected this to work like it does in other languages.

Comment: @KarlJacques: The sooner you relieve yourself of that expectation, the better. If all languages worked the same, then they wouldn't be different languages.

Answer (score 0):

You've detached the `run` method from the `app`. Pass a function that keeps them together.

```
setTimeout(function() { app.run(); }, 50);
```

Now the value of `this` in `.run()` will be the `app` object.

---

Also, there's no need to make a new `run` method for every `application()` object. You can put `run` on the `application.prototype`.

```
function application() {
   var canvas = Raphael(10,0,400,400);
   this.molecule = new molecule( new Vec2(50,50),new Vec2(1,0),canvas );
   this.molecule.update(10);
}

application.prototype.run =  function() {
    this.molecule.update(10);
}
```

---

Although if you *did* keep `run` in the constructor, you could then have it close over a variable that references the object, and so you could safely detach it.

```
function application() {
   var canvas = Raphael(10,0,400,400);
   this.molecule = new molecule( new Vec2(50,50),new Vec2(1,0),canvas );
   this.molecule.update(10);

   var self = this;

   this.run = function() {
       self.molecule.update(10);
   }
}
```

---

```
setTimeout(app.run, 50)
```